# WMI Entry Arrived Event accessing Event ID

Tags: wmi, event-log

I am having a small problem trying to get the Event ID when I use WMI to monitor the event log. Here is my code:

```
private static void EventLogMonitor(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    int realEventId = (int)(e.NewEvent.Properties["EventID"].Value);
    ...
```

But it fails to pick up the Event ID for me, just throwing an exception. Does anybody know what should go in place of **"EventID"** in the line of code above so that I can access the Event ID of the event log entry written event that fires this handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this, for anybody else that finds this useful here is the code:

```
private static void EventLogMonitor(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagementBaseObject targetInstance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent
                                                  .GetPropertyValue("TargetInstance");
    UInt16 EventId = (UInt16)(targetInstance.GetPropertyValue("EventCode"));
```